# How to create a REST API with .NET Framework?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.7

I created a project in Visual Studio 2022 with the main template "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)" and sub template "Web API".

[image]
[image]

This created a project with the ValuesController.

[image]

However, when I run the project and visit the url https://localhost:44342/api/values, I get the error:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

[image]

What do I have to do, to make this project work?

This is .NET Framework, not .NET Core, there is no launchSettings.json. The port is defined in the project file.

[image]

In the vbproj, there is this piece of xml:

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>53888</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>https://localhost:44342/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Comment: Did you check the port in the launchSettings.json? Is it 44324?

Comment: This is .NET Framework, not .NET Core, there is no launchSettings.json. The port is defined in the project file.

Comment: Might also be `https://localhost:44342/api/values` based on the (generated?) comment from the code

Comment: None of these urls work, they all display the message:

This site can’t be reached

Comment: Are you sure that your project is running because I created a project exactly like yours and I could access the `https://localhost:44342/api/Values` endpoint.